# Why is the accuracy of a Decision Tree decreasing whereas the accuracy of an LSTM is increasing when adding augmented data?

Tags: time-series, classification, cart, lstm, accuracy

I am using sklearn's `DecisionTreeClassifier` and LSTMs (Keras) for time series classification. To increase the accuracy and robustness of the models I augmented the training data set with jittered, interpolated, and warped data. The accuracy of the decision tree decreases from 89.35% to 88.12% whereas the accuracy of the LSTM increases from 92.61% to 94.32%. Is there a reason for that? The maximum depth of the Decision Tree is 16 and the criterion is entropy

```
tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=16)
```

and the following LSTM configuration

```
model_2_0 = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.LSTM(64, activation="relu", return_sequences = True, input_shape= (win_length, num_features)),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.LSTM(64, activation="relu", return_sequences=True),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.LSTM(64, activation="relu"),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(23, activation="softmax")                  
], name=model_name)
```

The data sets were really large, to begin with.
I am not quite sure how to interpret these results. What could be the reason here?

Comment: Is that accuracy evaluated on a separate test set? via repeated CV? Are we talking about training accuracy (which is usually pretty immaterial)? Something else?

Comment: I used the hold-out method. The test set is therefore identical for both models. I mentioned the test accuracies